# How to prevent an element from adding a class dynamically in asp menu?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have spent hours to solve this problem,but i didn't succeed. I am developing **asp menu** for the first time. Everything is fine,but when I hover the Menu item **.highlighted** css class gets added dynamically to the corresponding element.
Here is my code:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" StaticDisplayLevels="1" StaticSubMenuIndent="10" Orientation="horizontal" RenderingMode="List" CssClass="MenuClass">
 <Items>
       <asp:MenuItem Text="Dashboard" Target="" Value="Dashboard">
             <asp:MenuItem Text="Tasks" Value="Tasks"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="Call Backs" Value="Call Backs"></asp:MenuItem>
       </asp:MenuItem>

       <asp:MenuItem Text="Application" Value="Application">
              <asp:MenuItem Text="New" Value="New"></asp:MenuItem>
              <asp:MenuItem Text="View" Value="View"></asp:MenuItem>
       </asp:MenuItem>
 </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

This **asp:menu** in the webpage it is rendered as UL(unordered list) and LI(lists).

For the above code the html format rendered in the webpage is as follows:

```
<div class="MenuClass" id="Menu1" >
     <ul class="level1 static" role="menubar" >
       <li class="has-popup static" role="menuitem" >
          <a class="popout level1 static" href="#">Dashboard</a>
           <ul class="level2 dynamic" style="display:none">
              corresponding lists:  TASKS and CALLBACKS
           </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>

        Viceversa the ul and li for the Application MENUITEM are rendered as html 
</div>
```

In this what I need is, When I hover the menu **Dashboard** the sub menuitems **Tasks and Call Backs** will be shown, because the style for the UL with the class **level2 dynamic** changes to **display:block**. 
At the same time, a class named as **highlighted** is added dymanically to the  **tag and the class name becomes class="popout level1 static highlighted"** and  also automatically by the asp:menu functionality.
When the mouse leaves the Dashboard menu the added highlighted class gets removed dynamically and automatically.
I didn't know how the highlighted class gets added into the  **tag**.
My problem is to stop adding the **highlighted** class dynamically into the  tag, because I need to keep the style for the corresponding ul tag in the level2 as display:block.

When highlighted class is added, the style for the ul with the class name**level2 dynamic**
changes into display:block. But when the mouse leaves from the menu, it becomes as display:none.

In my project I have to keep the selected menu and its submenu as display:block until the another menu is clicked.

I have used JQUERY to make the submenus to be display:block for the selected menu.

I need to know how to stop or prevent adding the highlighted class to the a tag.
I think we can achieve it through jquery.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    if ($(".popout").hasClass("selected")) {
         $("a.popout.level1.selected.static").next("ul").css("display", "block");
    }

    if ($(".popout").hasClass("highlighted")) {
         $("a.popout.level1.selected.static.highlighted").next("ul").css("display","block");
    }

     $("a.popout.level1.selected.static.hihglighted").mouseout(function () {
                $("a.popout.level1.selected.static.highlighted").next("ul").css("display", "block");
                $("a.popout.level1.selected.static").next("ul").css("display","block");
                if ($("a.popout.level1.selected.static.highlighted").next("ul").css("display", "none")) {
                    $(".test").css("display", "block");
                }
            });
});
```

Here when the mouse leaves the menu, the highlighted class removed dynamically the css for the ul gets automatically as display:none, even as I had set it to be display:block it fails to be block. It displays none. So the addition of highlighted class is the worry on this case.

SO I have to stop the addition of the highlighted class to the **anchor tag**, so that the style will not be changed.

The adding of highlighted class didn't make any worries, but if it removes, the ul style becomes as display:none. I don't know why...?

Please help me on these issues..

Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: try to find where this class is added/removed instead of searching for a 'kind of workaround'...  But sorry, i don't know ASP

Comment: @roasted Thanks for your Quick reply. I am working with Jquery and what I need is, how to stop the highlighted class from adding. Is there any ideas for that...? Thanks in advance...:)

Comment: @user2309770: you need to show your jquery code.

Comment: @defau1t when I select a menu, the class names becomes as **<a class=popout level1 selected static></a>**, here the selected class gets added for the selected menuitem. I am finding the selected menu eith this **selected** class in the **popout** class. I'm editing my code for jquery.

Comment: @defau1t I have included my jquery code. Please see that and advise me on that issue.

Comment: Your code looks messy, but probably for the first 2 statements , you could just use redeuce the 4 lines to below statement:
$("a.popout.level1.selected.static").next("ul").toggle();

Comment: @defau1t I tried this but I didn't work. I have to find when does the highlighted class gets removed. How to find it...? Is there any ideas or way to find it...? I used mozilla firebug and kept breakpoints and checked. Till now I can't find the event where the highlighted class removed.

Comment: As I said before, your code is messy, putting this on jsfiddle.net would help.  Regarding your question I think this line is creating the issue
if ($("a.popout.level1.selected.static.highlighted").next("ul").css("display", "none")) {
                    $(".test").css("display", "block");
                }

you have a complex chain of css selectors, if you could reproduce this issue at www.jsfiddle.net maybe I can help.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this simple animation with that code :

```
        $("ul.level1 li a").mouseenter(function () {
            var ulhight = $(this).next("ul").height();
            $(this).next("ul").css({  "height": "0px", "overflow": "hidden" });
            $(this).next("ul").animate({ height: ulhight }, 300)
        })
```